# Spellchecker nonfunctional in English

Tags: spellchecking

Spellchecker doesn't correct as I type, and when I click "Check Spelling," it always says everything is fine, even though I've deliberately included errors (e.g., "spelting" instead of "spelling") as a test.

Comment: Spell checking is associated with your editor, not with (La)TeX.  Without more information, this question can't be answered, even by guessing.

Comment: Your spellchecker works correctly: spelting is a valid word. It means *present particle of spelt* ... Check your paper dictionary or just wiktionary .. ;-D